# AES encryption/decryption in rust: performance and best practices

Tags: performance, beginner, rust, aes

I wrote a small rust library [available on github](https://github.com/Sauro98/aes_s) that can encrypt/decrypt a 16 bytes block using either 128, 192 or 256 bit passwords. This implementation is tested with the test data provided in the [standard description](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf). Since I'm pretty new to rust and this was mainly an exercise to learn to use this language I would love to get feedback regarding code style and best practices. Also, I would be very interested in knowing how I could optimize it or in resources concerning that.

The function I feel could somehow use optimization the most is the mix_column transformation in the AES matrix:

```rust
    /**
     * Basically the inverse_mix_columns sets the bytes in each column to:
     *
     * col[0] = (col[0] * 0x02) xor (col[1] * 0x03) xor col[2] xor col[3]
     * col[1] = col[0] xor (col[1] * 0x02) xor (col[2] * 0x03) xor col[3]
     * col[2] = col[0] xor col[1] xor (col[2] * 0x02) xor (col[3] * 0x03)
     * col[3] = (col[0] * 0x03) xor col[1] xor col[2] xor (col[3] * 0x02)
     *
     * With '*' meaning the multiplication in the GF2 field as described by the AES standard
     */
    fn mix_column_8(bytes: &mut [u8; 16], offset: usize) {
        let mut column_bytes = [
            bytes[offset],
            bytes[offset + 1],
            bytes[offset + 2],
            bytes[offset + 3],
        ];
        for index in 0..4 {
            bytes[offset + index] = Math::x_time(column_bytes[0])
                ^ Math::multiplication_by_03(column_bytes[1])
                ^ column_bytes[2]
                ^ column_bytes[3];
            let temp = column_bytes[0];
            column_bytes[0] = column_bytes[1];
            column_bytes[1] = column_bytes[2];
            column_bytes[2] = column_bytes[3];
            column_bytes[3] = temp;
        }
    }
```

With the two external functions called being:

```rust
pub fn x_time(val: u8) -> u8 {
        if val > 0x7f {
            (val << 1) ^ 0x1b
        } else {
            val << 1
        }
}

pub fn multiplication_by_03(val: u8) -> u8 {
    (val ^ Self::x_time(val))
}
```

This is my first post on here so I hope that it fits the rules, otherwise I'll be happy to edit it.